# SELECT which should give the number of unique n in an 1:n realtionship

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Hello i've got a short question.

For an exercise at the university i've got a full joined table.

In this table is a column called supplier and a column prduct_id.

Now i want to make a select which does the following:

I want to get the number of unique (DISTINCT) product_id's for each supplier

i've tried the following, but it give me the number of all row's grouped by the supplier

```
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(`product_code`),`id_supplier` FROM `refactored_data`
    GROUP BY `refactored_data`.`id_supplier` ORDER BY 
    `refactored_data`.`id_supplier` ASC
```

Comment: you should place DISTINCT in COUNT() a given below
 COUNT( DISTINCT `product_code`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id), id_supplier
FROM refactored_data
GROUP BY id_supplier
```

So it seems your query is actually simpler than you think.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by supplier and count products. Then you say you only want distinct results, which doesn't change anything, because your results are already unique.

Move the DISTINCT inside your COUNT, so as to count distinct values, rather then making your lines distinct.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_code), id_supplier
FROM refactored_data
GROUP BY id_supplier
ORDER BY id_supplier ASC;
```